# How to reduce the space between the title and the first heading?

Tags: spacing, titlesec

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,usenames,dvipsnames,a4paper]{article}
\linespread{1}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                ext.paths.ortho}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows.meta}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{expdlist}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{biblatex}
 \usepackage{asymptote}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={7.5in, 9.5in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{caption}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{>=latex} % for LaTeX arrow head
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.9}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\title{How does varying the capacitance between $\qty{0.01}{ \micro \farad}$ and $\qty{10}{\micro \farad}$, $(10, 4.7, 2.2, 1, 0.47, 0.22, 0.1, 0.047, 0.022, 0.01)$, while keeping inductance and resistance constant at $\qty{10}{\milli \henry}$ and $\qty{100}{\ohm}$ respectively, affect the peak frequency of the input voltage?}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\pagenumbering{arabic}


\textcolor{Emerald}{\section{Introduction}}

\noindent Capacitors are commonly found in our daily home appliances. They are often used to store a charge which is later discharged to produce a current. Capacitors are formed by assembling 2 parallel conducting plates and inserting a dielectric material between them. When a voltage is applied between these plates, this sets up an electric field between them and allows the capacitor to store charge and therefore electrical potential energy. An RLC circuit is a circuit which consists of a Resistor, Inductor and Capacitor. They are connected in series for this experiment. RLC circuits have a variety of crucial applications. Because of this, studying them is essential in the fields of electrical engineering and electronics. RLC can also be used to amplify signals at specific resonant frequency. Examples of such applications can be found in radio receivers. \\

\end{document}
```

Which produces the following: [image]

I am interested in using the titlesec package in order to remove the whitespace between the title and the first heading. How can I do this?

Comment: What't the purpose of running `\pagenumbering{roman}` followed immediately by
`\pagenumbering{arabic}`? What's the prpose of running `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}` twice? Plaese do yourself a big favor and remove the cruft from the preamble.

Comment: @Mico I used to have a contents page, which I used the roman page numbering for. But since I removed it, I forgot to remove that too. My preamble is looking much better now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use titlesec to change that space. If you redefine the section command, this will change all sections, not just the first one. Instead I would use a negative space to hide the room which normally shows the author and date.

Some other points:

- you should really clean up your preamble. You must not load the same package multiple times with conflicting options.
- the `times` package is obsolete, don't use it
- use the `\qty` macro from siunitx to get correct spacing between your numbers and units

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\title{How does varying the capacitance between \qty{0.01}{\micro \farad}}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\vspace*{-4\baselineskip}

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

[image]